# Sequence-Function convergence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Consider $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =
0$. For each $n \geq 1$, define $y_n = \min\{|x_1|, \ldots,
|x_n|\}$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = 0$.

I tried this way:

Given that for all $\epsilon >0,$

$|x_n-0|<\epsilon$. Then

$||x_n|-|0||\leq|x_n-0|<\epsilon$. Then it implies that $|x_n|\rightarrow 0$.

since $y_n=\min\{|x_1|, \ldots,
|x_n|\}\leq|x_n|, \forall n\geq 0$.

Then $y_n\rightarrow 0.$ Is my argument correct?

Comment: How have you attempted to attack the problem?

Answer (score 1):

$0 \le y_n \le |x_n|$. The sandwich lemma says $y_n \to 0$.